# why doesn't my image_tag work?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Iamge_tag:

```
<%= image_tag ("face9", :class => "style_image") %>
```

css:

```
.style_image {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

error:

C:/Sites/AcuSimonv/app/views/acupuntura/inicio.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...er.append=( image_tag ("face9", :class => ".style_image") );... ... ^ C:/Sites/AcuSimonv/app/views/acupuntura/inicio.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...9", :class => ".style_image") );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^

Comment: That image_tag line is correct so your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Ruby is (somewhat) whitespace-sensitive. If you're going to use method-calling parentheses then you shouldn't put a space between the method and the `(`. `m(x)` and `m (x)` are different things but the difference is invisible, `m(x, y)` and `m (x, y)` are different things but the difference is noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space between `image_tag` and `(`:

```
<%= image_tag("face9", :class => "style_image") %>
```

[image_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)